# ERROR: INVALID_RESPONSE - Data is returning from promise but can't get Alexa to speak/show card

Tags: node.js, lambda, es6-promise, alexa-skills-kit

I have two https requests in nodejs, the first to confirm a user is authorized to access the data, and the second is to return the data.

I have console logs throughout and I see the data is successfully being returned in the promise, but Alexa won't speak/show the card. There are no errors in cloudwatch.

I don't fully understand the promise syntax so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I've been changing up the syntax, trying async/await, and nothing seems to be working.

**EDITED CODE** - with some help, I was able to better lay out my code. I am now getting the error in cloud watch: **ERROR: INVALID_RESPONSE, An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill.**

Note: this error is occuring because right now I am FORCING an error, aka the top part (if redacted.errors).

messages.NO_ACCESS is currently set to ---- "Hmm, it seems like you don't have access to that data."

```
const IntentRequest = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
        let resp, resultData;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         checkAuthenticationStatus(handlerInput, function(json){

            if(REDACTED.errors) {
                console.log('unauthed', REDACTED.error)
                reject(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(messages.NO_ACCESS).withSimpleCard('Unauthorized Request', messages.NO_ACCESS).getResponse());

            } else if(REDACTED.noerror && REDACTED.noerror.data == 'true'){
                const url = new URL(REDACTED.url);

               const resp = httpsGetIntent(handlerInput, url, (theResult) => {
                    resultData = theResult;
                    console.log('resolved with ---->', d)
                    return resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak("The result was" + d).withSimpleCard('Hello World', d).getResponse());
                })

            }

        })

        });

    },
};
```

Here's the part of the code where the data IS (resultData and d are the same thing and both return data) returned but she doesn't speak/show card:

```
const IntentRequest = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest';
    },
     handle(handlerInput) {
        const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
        let resp, resultData;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            checkAuthenticationStatus(handlerInput, function(json){
                if(REDACTED) {
                reject(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(messages.NO_ACCESS).withSimpleCard('Unauthorized Request', messages.NO_ACCESS).getResponse())

            } else if(REDACTED && REDACTED == 'true'){
                const url = new URL(REDACTED);

                resp = httpsGetIntent(handlerInput, url, (theResult) => {
                    resultData = theResult;
                    console.log(resultData)
                }).then((d) => { 
                    console.log(d)
                    resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak("The result was" + d.response.outputSpeech.text).withSimpleCard('Hello World', d.response.outputSpeech.text).getResponse());
                }).catch((err) => { console.log(err)});

            }

        });

        });

    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In arrow notation, `.then((d) => resolve(x))` will return the resolve, because the call to resolve is on the same line, but if you `.then(() => { // more than one line })` I think you just need to explicitly call `return`.

```
const IntentRequest = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
    // do you need resp here?
    let resp, resultData;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      checkAuthenticationStatus(handlerInput, function(json){
        // does REDACTED know about json?
        if(!REDACTED) {
          reject(handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(messages.NO_ACCESS)
            .withSimpleCard('Unauthorized Request', messages.NO_ACCESS)
            .getResponse());
        } else if(REDACTED && REDACTED == 'true') {
          const url = new URL(REDACTED);
          httpsGetIntent(handlerInput, url, (resultData) => {
            console.log(resultData);
            return resultData;
          }).then((d) => {
            resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder
              .speak("The result was" + d.response.outputSpeech.text)
              .withSimpleCard("Hello World", d.response.outputSpeech.text)
              .getResponse());
          }).catch((err) => { console.log(err)});
        }
      });
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks! I just added the return before it, but nothing seems to have changed. @benhulan

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you have to consider and are not clear in the question.

What is REDACTED here, where does that value come from ? you have not mentioned it anywhere.

Let's assume it's a global variable for the sake of convenience.

If REDACTED is false for any reason then your code is never gonna executed. Because the condition is never met. So that promise neither rejects nor resolves.

If am assuming you have mistakenly written REDACTED in the first if statement, it should be !REDACTED probably.

```
 resp = httpsGetIntent(handlerInput, url, theResult => {
              resultData = theResult;
              console.log(resultData);
            })
            .then(d => {
              console.log(d);
              resolve(
                handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak("The result was" + d.response.outputSpeech.text)
                .withSimpleCard("Hello World", d.response.outputSpeech.text)
                .getResponse()
              );
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
```

Here the *httpsGetIntent* is also not correct, You are having a callback method which receives *theResult* and yet attaching a then method, which doesn't make any sense. Moreover *resultData* is not doing anything here.

Assuming that *checkAuthenticationStatus* and *httpGetIntent* both have a callback pattern, You could write something like this

```
const IntentRequest = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest";
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const {
      requestEnvelope,
      serviceClientFactory,
      responseBuilder
    } = handlerInput;
    let resp, resultData;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      checkAuthenticationStatus(handlerInput, function (json) {
        if (!REDACTED) {
          reject(
            handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(messages.NO_ACCESS)
            .withSimpleCard("Unauthorized Request", messages.NO_ACCESS)
            .getResponse()
          );
        } else if (REDACTED && REDACTED == "true") {
          const url = new URL(REDACTED);

          httpsGetIntent(handlerInput, url, theResult => {
            resultData = theResult;
            console.log(resultData);
           return resolve(
              handlerInput.responseBuilder
              .speak("The result was" + d.response.outputSpeech.text)
              .withSimpleCard("Hello World", d.response.outputSpeech.text)
              .getResponse()
            );
          })
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for this! Sorry for being unclear - I just did not want to share sensitive data/data structures.

it's the json response from my authentication function, top part is if it returns with an error and bottom part is if it returns with authentication + data for where to route the second request.

I made updates based on what you said and am now getting "ERROR: INVALID_RESPONSE, An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."

i will update my code above

Comment: Thanks! I understand you concern. you can actually post dummy code :)

Comment: I updated my above code matching the format you suggested with more info on REDACTED. REDACTED is the value passed back from the checkAuthenticationStatus callback (json)

Comment: ERROR: INVALID_RESPONSE, An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill.

Comment: Are you able to debug the code ? and one more thing `REDACTED && REDACTED == "true" ` this is intentional right

Comment: if(REDACTED.errors) {
                console.log('unauthed', REDACTED.error)
                reject(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(messages.NO_ACCESS).withSimpleCard('Unauthorized Request', messages.NO_ACCESS).getResponse());

            } 

This is what is returning at the moment, Im forcing REDACTED.errors to be true

Comment: Since Im forcing errors to be true, Im not even processing the returned data response so it's just a hardcoded string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193900/discussion-between-saroj-and-almost-ashleigh).